# Extract substring in Linux environemnt using Sed/awk/grep or any other tool

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

I just want to get the substring from a specific string.

For example, I have `"sec(name=test)"` string. And, I want to extract `name=test` string using shell.

I have tried below command to extract `"name=test"` value. But, I got result as `sec()`

```
echo "sec(name=test)"| grep -P '(sec\((.*)\))'
```

Could you please help to fix?

Comment: Please don't ask for a tutorial. You should ask a specific question for a particular programming problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @jww 
I have tried to extract using below command. But, I got the result like sec().
But, I want to get the name=test.
echo "sec(name=test)"| grep -P '(sec\((.*)\))'

Comment: this should work `grep -oP '\(\K[^)]+'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, but unless you want `egrep` (that may or may not be available), `sed` with basic-regular-expressions will do, e.g.

```
$ echo "sec(name=test)"| sed 's/^[^(]*(\([^)]*\)).*$/\1/'
name=test
```

The details for the standard substitute command are `s/find/replace/` where the `find` part is somewhat a setup to collect a *backreference* to use in the `replace` part of the command. For instance,

**The `find` part**

1. `^` - anchor to begin match at start of string
2. `[^(]*` - match all characters in the `[..class..]`, that are `"^("` (not an opening paren)
3. `(` - consume the opening paren
4. `\(...\)` collect characters to save as a backreference, those characters being `"[^)]*` everything not a closing paren,
5. `)` - consume the closing paren,
6. `.*$` - the rest of the line.

**The `replace` part**

7. `\1` insert the characters saved as the first backreference (the stuff between `\(...\)` which in your case was `name=test`.

And, you are done...

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation @David C.Rankin 
Its woking as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` will print the matching line, or with `-o` the string which matched. The capturing parentheses by themselves don't do anything to change this.

There is a way with `grep -P` to say "match the stuff inside the parentheses, but only when the following lookarounds also match" so you could do

```
echo "sec(name=test)"| grep -oP '(?<=sec\().*?(?=\))'
```

The lookbehind `(?<=sec\()` says the match must be immediately preceded by `sec(` and the lookahead `(?=\))` similarly requires the match to be followed by `)`.  I changed the match expression from greedy `.*` to the stingy `.*?` to avoid having it straddle across a set of parentheses. There is of course the possibility that this isn't precisely what you want; your question doesn't reveal what text we should expect to match (in particular, can it contain nested parentheses?)

This is pretty convoluted, though; the much simpler and portable solution is to use `sed` to replace the things before and after the desired string with nothing, then print.

```
echo "sec(name=test)"| sed -n 's/.*sec\(([^()]*)\).*/\1/p'
```

Notice how the regex dialect used by `sed` is simpler than what `grep -P` supports, and in particular, unquoted parentheses `()` match literally, while backslashed ones are used for grouping -- the opposite of how they work in Perl and e.g. `egrep`.

Answer (score 0):

With Gnu-Sed, you may as well write

```
 echo "sec(name=test)"| sed -r 's/sec\(([^)]*)\)/\1/'
```

With sed -r, your round parens needn't be masked, when used for grouping, but when meant literally. See the **man sed** for more details.

This looks for sec(, then for an arbitrary number of characters, which aren't the closing parens, then the closing parens.

Comment: `-r` is not portable; some dialects use `-E` instead, and some `sed` implementations do not support extended regular expressions at all.

Comment: You're right. Most Linuxes come with Gnu-sed, but of course it's not guaranteed.